# How to see IL of a class/method in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, il

I had nice VS2010 extension (called Ndasm I think). However it is not compatible with VS2012.

Is there a way I can see the IL of a class or a method immediately in design time?

Comment: [IL-visualizer](https://github.com/drewnoakes/il-visualizer) is a maintained project that does this, and works with current versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try downloading the [source code to NDasm from Codeplex](http://ndasm.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f05278a57f5a) and attempt to build it for VS2012. Give it a try, this is why open source is cool.

Alternately there are external tools for viewing IL code.
[.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) (not free)
[JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (free)

Note: [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) does not currently support viewing IL but that feature/issue can be viewed and/or voted for [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DOTP-286).

Comment: I am complete moron. I had reflector for ages and didnt know it shows IL.